# iso 8583 Unpacking error field 123 arrayindexout of bound

Tags: java, iso, jpos

I am using `JPOS` to pack and unpack `ISO` message the packing of the message is just good and when I get the following reply

```
1210E030000002000020000000000400002807110457626000026000000052220140909134530000001812UU2411906554003TCB48520141026|20141026|D|UG|142465.75|Interest Paid||20991780.75^20140930|20140930|D|UG|164383.55|Interest Paid||20849315^20140831|20140831|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20684931.45^20140731|20140731|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20515068.45^20140630|20140630|D|UG|164383.55|Interest Paid||20345205.45^20140531|20140531|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20180821.9^20140430|20140430|D|UG|10958.90|Interest Paid||20010958.9^20140429|20140429|D|UG|20000000.00|Deposit Created||20000000.00
```

When I try to unpack it I get the following error:

```
error unpacking field 123
org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 123 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 592)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOStringFieldPackager.unpack(ISOStringFieldPackager.java:178)
org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 123 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 592)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:233)
```

Comment: i am not soo good in JPOS, but i will try to help, what packager are you using?

Comment: is it `ISO93APackager`, you are using ISO 8583-2:1993 version?

Comment: I am using ISO 8583:1987 packager. This is what I got from the iso87ascii.xml.

Comment: i used that packager, but, the error was `unpacking field=102` however, if i delete the first char from left, i start getting success unpack, and keep deleting , all is success but with different dump msg, so try it, and if you can post the original message here too, i will post an answer to make it clear.

Comment: Yazan that is the original reply from the socket

Comment: I got the solution here https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/dist/cfg/packager/test-generic-validating-packager.xml. It was a packager issue. Thanks

Comment: so you was using the wrong packager?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i used

```
ISOMsg msg = new ISOMsg();

try {
    msg.setPackager(new GenericPackager("iso87ascii.xml"));
    msg.unpack(str.getBytes("UTF8"));

    msg.dump(System.out, "");
} catch (ISOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you start removing first chars, you will start getting results, as following:

```
str="210E030000002000020000000000400002807110457626000026000000052220140909134530000001812UU2411906554003TCB48520141026|20141026|D|UG|142465.75|Interest Paid||20991780.75^20140930|20140930|D|UG|164383.55|Interest Paid||20849315^20140831|20140831|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20684931.45^20140731|20140731|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20515068.45^20140630|20140630|D|UG|164383.55|Interest Paid||20345205.45^20140531|20140531|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20180821.9^20140430|20140430|D|UG|10958.90|Interest Paid||20010958.9^20140429|20140429|D|UG|20000000.00|Deposit Created||20000000.00";
```

Output:

```
<isomsg>
  <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[iso87ascii.xml] -->
  <field id="0" value="210E"/>
  <field id="7" value="0000000040"/>
  <field id="8" value="00028071"/>
  <field id="35" value="4576260000"/>
  <field id="55" value="00000052220140909134530000001812UU2411906554003TCB48520141026|20141026|D|UG|142465.75|Interest Paid||20991780.75^20140930|20140930|D|UG|164383.55|Interest Paid||20849315^20140831|20140831|D|UG|169863.00|Interest Paid||20684931.45^20140731|20140731|D|UG|169863."/>
</isomsg>
```

if you remove the '2' from begin of str:

```
<isomsg>
  <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[iso87ascii.xml] -->
  <field id="0" value="10E0"/>
  <field id="3" value="000000"/>
  <field id="4" value="040000280711"/>
  <field id="31" value="045762600"/>
  <field id="51" value="002"/>
</isomsg>
```

and so on...

if you remove the whole `1210E`, you will get

```
<isomsg>
  <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[iso87ascii.xml] -->
  <field id="0" value="0300"/>
  <field id="19" value="000"/>
  <field id="39" value="04"/>
</isomsg>
```

which i find logic, as it have iso39 (response)

i am not sure if this is for a help, but it could give you a clue,

Comment: Yazan thanks. but the string starts with 1210-MTI this the reply that comes from the server socket so using it as it is is better.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/dist/cfg/packager/test-generic-validating-packager.xml it was a packager issue. I have used the packager and it works correctly. If the packager on the server side is different from the client side, then an error is likely to occur.